# .NET Windows Form app mysql database query

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am learning C# and as part of a exercise with .Net I need to give the user a form with from , to and amount fields and when user hits the transfer button. The application should deduct the amount from the from account_id and add the money to To account_id

This is my button function code

```
string mysql_conn_string = "server=localhost;user=root;database=vsp;port=3306;password=password";
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(mysql_conn_string);
                con.Open();
                string s1 = "update bank set amount = amount - " + textBox3.Text + "where account_id = " + textBox1.Text;
                string s2 = "update bank set amount = amount + " + textBox3.Text + "where account_id = " + textBox2.Text;

                MySqlTransaction tx = con.BeginTransaction();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(s1, con, tx);
                int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(s2, con, tx);
                int b = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (a == 0 || b == 0)
                {
                    tx.Rollback();
                    MessageBox.Show("Rolling bacck");
                }
                else
                {
                    tx.Commit();
                    MessageBox.Show("Transaction Succesful");
                }
                con.Close();
```

I am getting the following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySqlserver version for the right syntax to use near 'account_id = 2` at line 1

But the same sql statements are working correctly in mysql workbench and not showing any errors.

My table has account_id and amount columns.

Both are of INT

I have tried changing the textbox type to INT by using both Int32.Parse
and Int64.Parse

Comment: Examine the value of `s1` and `s2` after they are created.  That's one of *many* reasons why you should never concat values and strings to make SQL.  Use DBParameters *always*

Comment: Thank you the problem was there is no space before where statement. and also I still did not reach the DBParameters stage in C# yet I will surely be using them in the future, Thank you for helping

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I'm seeing, the error isn't on the WHERE condition but on the data because you need add one space. You have this:

```
string s1 = "update bank set amount = amount - " + textBox3.Text + "where account_id = " + textBox1.Text;
string s2 = "update bank set amount = amount + " + textBox3.Text + "where account_id = " + textBox2.Text;
```

Then, when the query is built you will have this:

```
s1 = "update bank set amount = amount - 100where account_id = 1";
```

As you can see, the WHERE and the text on textBox3 are together, try add one space like this:

```
string s1 = "update bank set amount = amount - " + textBox3.Text + " where account_id = " + textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Thank you Luis for your answer for some reason your answer was displayed late I will be deleting my answer

Answer (score 1):

**You have a number of serious issues in your code**

1. Your primary issue: a syntax error because of a missing space.
2. You would have spotted that quicker if you had parameterized your query properly, to avoid SQL injection.
3. You need to dispose all `Sql` objects with a `using` (and then you don't need to call `Close` explicitly).
4. You can execute the two statements in one go.
5. There is no need to conditionally rollback if it doesn't work. Instead check if the rows exist.
6. You should not hard-code the connection string, put it into a Settings file instead.
7. Don't block the thread with a message-box while the ocnnection is open.

```cs
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.ConnectionString))
{
    const string query = @"
start transaction;

if (select count(*)
    from bank
    where account_id in (@s1, @s2)
   ) = 2 then
    update bank
    set amount = amount + (case when account_id = @s1 then -@amt else @amt end)
    where account_id in (@s1, @s2);
end if;

commit;
";
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s1", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s2", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amt", textBox3.Text);
        con.Open();
        rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

if (rows == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not executed");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Transaction Succesful");
}
```